# I'm having trouble performing arithmetic expressions in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, math

I have the following script:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  r=3
  r=$((r+5))
  echo r
```

However, I get this error:

Syntax error at line 3: $ unexpected.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm following this online guide to the letter http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/06/arithmetic-operations-in-unix-scripts/

Comment: You'd probably need `echo $r` instead of `echo r` anyway.

Comment: `((r = r + 5))` or `((r += 5))`  should also both work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds fine if you're using `bash`, but `$((r+5))` might not be supported if you're using another shell. What does `/bin/sh` point to? Have you considered replacing it with `/bin/bash` if it's available?

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The shebang line is your problem. bash is not sh. Change it to `#!/bin/bash` and it will work. You'll also want `echo $r` instead of `echo r`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (printing `8`), if you change `echo r` to `echo $r`. What version of `sh` do you have installed? What unix distribution?

Comment: If it works for you, it's because your sh is bash, and bash is not strict about forbidding bash-specific extensions while running as sh

Comment: @Daenyth: yup you're right, `/bin/sh --version` prints `GNU bash, ...` for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following:

```
#!/bin/sh  
r=3  
r=$((r + 5))  
echo $r
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing maths (including decimals/floats), you can use `awk`or `bc/dc`.

```
awk -vr="$r" 'BEGIN{r=r+5;print r}'
```

or

```
echo "$r+5" | bc
```